# R package development: testthat fails because of not verified subfunction in Mclust package

Tags: r, testthat, mclust

I am developing an R package and **testthat** library is applied for verification. The error issue happens when loading function from external Mclust package (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mclust/index.html) that includes anonymous function inside. This function is not recognised by using *requireNamespace()*. Here is code example:

```
get.enr.bg.normfit <- function(x) {
    result <- c(NA, NA)
    if (requireNamespace("mclust")) {
      names(result) <- c("mean","sd")
      # fit two normal distributions to data
      # model <- Mclust(na.omit(x), G=2, modelNames="V")
      model <- mclust::Mclust(na.omit(x), G=2)
    ...
```

The test runs, but can not find additional mclust function inside:

*Error: transcritpt type missing mark (@test-expr-filter.R#53) ---------------
could not find function "mclustBIC*

The problem that Mclust calls mclustBIC from anonymous function inside. The same issue occurs when running full package check in RStudio.

*Loading required namespace: mclust
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function "mclustBIC"
Calls: filterGeneExpr -> get.enr.bg.normfit ->  -> eval -> eval*

Is there any strategy to fix this?
I can also fully depend on the package mclust, but this function is optional therefore it makes sense only to use require option.